# How to test a Sidekiq worker with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, sidekiq, rspec-sidekiq

I'm doing a test using RSPEC, and used Sidekiq for background jobs.

Since, there's no generator for `workers` in rspec, not sure what to use.

https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/generators

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe TestWorker, type: ? do # ex. :worker :sidekiq ...
  describe "TestWorker" do
    it "" do
     ....
    end
  end
end
```

`bundle exec rspec spec/workers/test_worker_spec.rb`

Doing like below, i'm getting: `uninitialized constant TestWorker`
    require 'spec_helper'

```
describe TestWorker do
  it "" do
   ....
  end
end
```

As i tried, `gem rspec-sidekiq`
https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq

Can someone provide a sample template for testing `app/workers/` in Rspec.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not used the rspec-sidekiq gem, however, here is an example of how I am checking for Background jobs which uses sidekiq

```
# app/spec/workers/demo_worker_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.fake!

RSpec.describe DemoWorker, type: :worker do

  describe "Sidekiq Worker" do

    let (:demo) { FactoryGirl.create(:demo) }

    it "should respond to #perform" do
      expect(DemoWorker.new).to respond_to(:perform)
    end

    describe "Demo" do

      before do
        Sidekiq::Extensions.enable_delay!
        Sidekiq::Worker.clear_all
      end

      it "should enqueue a Email and SMS job" do
        assert_equal 0, Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer.jobs.size
        Mailer.delay.demo_request(demo.id)
        assert_equal 1, Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer.jobs.size
      end

    end

  end

end
```

1. As of I'm checking, if the instance responds to perform.
2. Then, I'm asserting before and after the job is scheduled.

Comment: Thanks it works, i mixed up thing before. Any idea on checking with sidekiq_options :queue => my_queue like
 
it { is_expected.to be_processed_in :my_queue }

Comment: Are you trying to test the queue ? If so, take a look here - https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing#queue-api-40. I have not tried this though.

Comment: just wanna check that the queue name exists :)

Comment: Try [this](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/matchers/have-enqueued-job-matcher#checking-job-queue-name)

Answer (score 0):

You might sometimes want to test more than just the fact that the worker has been enqueud or not.

While it is better to decouple complex stuff that could happen in a worker's `perform` block, it can be tested as a standard class :

```
it { expect { MyWorker.new.perform }.to change { ...expectations... } }
```

or

```
it do
  MyWorker.new.perform
  ... expectations ..
end
```

Comment: Best to have at least some coverage around the queue. This doesn't test sidekiq can actually perform the job. I got caught out this way because my arguments were not proper JSON.

Comment: Better sticking with the positional Arguments rather than using keyword arguments (json?), so then no need to think too much if sidekiq can perform depending on your input - it will just work. `MyWorker.new.perform` let you test as you would with standard classes. Testing if the job is enqued (the Have_enqueued_job matcher) is pointless if you actually want to test the job output